# I want to user orderBy by giving specific order of role

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, sql-order-by

I've roles like lead > collaborator > participant > viewer. If I use
orderBy(role) then getting order as collaborator > lead > participant > viewer
If I do DESC order then getting reverse.

I tried specifying order in SQL and it's working as expected getting lead > collaborator > participant > viewer

`ORDER BY ROLE = 'viewer', ROLE = 'participant', ROLE = 'collaborator', ROLE = 'lead';`

The same I want to achieve in Java Spring Boot. How can I?

Comment: not sure if there is a JPA-compliant way to do this. We can, however, always write [native queries (`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native).

Comment: order by `CASE WHEN role='viewer' THEN 1 WHEN role='participant' THEN 2 WHEN role='collaborator' THEN 3  ELSE 4 END` asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this by specifying the order

```
.orderBy(field("role").sortAsc("lead", "collaborator", "participant", "viewer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create this method in your service :

```sql
public List<ConcoursAdministratifRe> getListByRole() {
String queryRecherche = "SELECT t FROM YourEntityName t ORDER BY (CASE role WHEN 'viewer' THEN 1 WHEN 'participant' THEN 2 WHEN 'lead' THEN 3 WHEN 'collaborator' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END) ASC";
TypedQuery<YourEntityName > query = em.createQuery(queryRecherche, YourEntityName.class);
List<YourEntityName> myList = query.getResultList();
return myList;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If your roles are static (seldom if ever changes) then you can accomplish this by creating a `enum` ([Create Emun](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.5) and [Alter Type enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) ) for them. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_fwuNrz))

```
create type role_enum as enum ('collaborator', 'lead', 'participant', 'viewer');
 
create table test ( id   integer  generated always as identity
                                  primary key 
                  , name text
                  , role role_enum
                  ) ;
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this in your obscurification manager (Spring Boot) so you will have to translate it or use raw sql.